# Problemas con las carga de los config XML de spring y spring security

Tags: jsf, spring, spring-security

Buenas tengo problemas para inplementar el spring security, ya tenia configurado anteriormente el spring freamworks y sus beans y funciona perfecto. Ahora que he puesto el spring security los beans cuando lo usa java me da error de NullPointer. El problema se elimina si uno le quita el spring security, lo cual no es la idea. Dejo los archivos principales.

Web.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Faces-Config.XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/Logins.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Security/Inicio.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Spring-Config.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd">

<!-- support spring annotation -->
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- support annotation transaction -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- declare datasource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/controlgasto" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- declare datasource -->
<bean id="dataSourceMysqlInicial"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!--Hibernate session factory configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- load hibernate configuration file -->
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <!-- where to find the ORM classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.controlGasto.hibernate.model" />
</bean>

<!--Hibernate session factory configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactoryMySQL"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMysqlInicial" />
    <!-- load hibernate configuration file -->
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- service -->
<bean id="usuarioService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.UsuarioServiceImpl" />
<bean id="efectivoService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.EfectivoServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="calendarioService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.CalendarioServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="crearBaseDatoService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.CrearBaseDatoServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="java_LocaleService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.Java_LocaleServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="configuracionService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.ConfiguracionServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="tipo_OperacionService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.Tipo_OperacionServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="banco_listadoService" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.services.Banco_ListadoServiceImpl"/>

<!-- dao -->
<bean id="usuarioDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.UsuarioDaoImpl" />
<bean id="efectivoDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.EfectivoDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="calendarioDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.CalendarioDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="crearBaseDatoDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.CrearBaseDatoDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="java_LocaleDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.Java_LocaleDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="configuracionDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.ConfiguracionDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="tipo_OperacionDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.Tipo_OperacionDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="banco_listadoDao" class="com.controlGasto.hibernate.DAO.Banco_listadoDaoImpl"/>

<!--SPRING SECURITY ENCRIPTING-->
<bean id="encriptar" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="12"/>
</bean>
<bean id="loginBean" class="com.controlGasto.jsf.beans.Login.LoginBean">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

Spring-Security.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean:beans xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

<bean:import resource="spring-config.xml"/>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/Security/**" access="ROLE_Usuario" />
    <form-login login-page="/Logins.xhtml"
                default-target-url="/index.xhtml"
                authentication-failure-url="/Login-Error.xhtml"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encriptar"/>
        <user-service>
            <user name="manuel"  password="$2a$12$d/9IWBc1AVHifA9g4cDzuev3T28yS6BXu7Y1Jm6HSQjtZp8eq84LO" authorities="ROLE_Usuario" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: `me da error de NullPointer` y el error es..?

Comment: Los managed properties que uso en java no se cargan con los datos

Comment: Y la traza del `NullPointer`?